Having trouble with simple kNN regression code on Harvard data science with python course. Can't figure out how to debug it
My last group of code continues to give me a value error: Expected a 2-dimensional container but got <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. I believe this is due to code earlier on that (although free of bugs, does not work with this later code). first errors with associated code
Here is the later code with the errors I am receiving. I am new to data science, and have tried multiple methods to solve this issue, but can't seem to find anything that works. last strings of code with associated errors
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying to debug this for over a day now.
For the first error, I am very confused. I changed the brackets and added the additional (first line) of code, which returned less errors, but a new error none the less. For the second error, I tried multiple variations using pandas to modify the code to return a 2-dimensional container, but it continues to return the same error.

Your data is a 1 Dimensional series...
Try to make sure your x data is a dataframe or 2 dimensional
